# regex in brackets: x or higher

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a mongodb query and I want all numbers with E-9, E-10,.. as from 9 till ...

I have following:

```
 {$regex: ".*E-.[9]"}}
```

which will give all matches with E-9 at the end. How can I do something like:

```
[9+]
```

to match everything that is higher than 9

Comment: Greater than or `9`: `^(9|[1-9][0-9]+)$`

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? `.*E-[9]` rather than `.*E-.[9]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, this did the trick: {$regex: ".*E-(9|[1-9][0-9]+)"}